# How do I replace all occurrences of a given string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript? I tried:

```
string.replaceAll('aa', 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a regex with the g flag you can replace all instances in one replace call.

```
var str = ...;
var regex = /aa/g;

str.replace(regex, 'b');
```